# Speedup DataFrame resampling

Tags: pandas, numpy, numba

I need to compute the daily return from hour h1 to hour h2, on a datetime-indexed dataframe.
I can do this with asfreq and resample calls but it's quite slow. For example, assuming h1=0 and h2=3:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_index = pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=2 * 365 * 24, freq="H")
df_data = np.random.randn(2 * 365 * 24, 250)
df = pd.DataFrame(df_data, index=df_index)

df.asfreq("3H").pct_change().resample("D", closed="right", label="right", offset="3H").last()
```

My attemps at using numba are unsuccessful, as I observe a slower timing.

I tried two versions, one processing the full df, one column by column, with arguments idx, col, data being numpy arrays, h1 and h2 being int64 scalars.

What am I doing wrong?

```
@numba.njit(error_model="numpy")  # expected to be multiples faster
def pct_change_h1_h2_njit(idx, data, h1, h2):
    out = np.full_like(data, np.nan)
    zeroes = np.full_like(out[0], 0)
    denominator = out[0]

    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if idx[i] == h1:
            denominator = v
        elif idx[i] == h2:
            if np.isnan(denominator).all():
                out[i] = zeroes
            else:
                out[i] = np.divide(v, denominator) - 1

    return out


@numba.njit
def pct_change_col_h1_h2_njit(idx, col, h1=0, h2=3):
    out = np.full_like(col, np.nan)
    exceptions = np.array([np.nan, 0, np.inf, -np.inf])
    denominator = np.nan

    for i, v in enumerate(col):
        if idx[i] == h1:
            denominator = v
        elif idx[i] == h2:
            if denominator in exceptions:
                out[i] = 0
            else:
                out[i] = v / denominator - 1

    return out
```

Running timeit on the three equivalent methods shows that the njit versions are more than twice as slow.

```
%timeit for x in range(1000):
    df.asfreq("3H").pct_change().resample(
        "D", closed="right", label="right", offset="3H"
    ).last()
# 25 s ± 5.72 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit for x in range(1000):
    pd.DataFrame(
        pct_change_h1_h2_njit(df.index.hour.values, df.values, 0, 3), 
        index=df.index, columns=df.columns
    ).dropna(how="all")
# 59.9 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit 
for x in range(1000):
    pd.concat(
        [
            pd.Series(
                pct_change_col_h1_h2_njit(
                    idx=np.array(df.index.hour, dtype=np.int64),
                    col=df[c].values,
                    h1=0,
                    h2=3,
                )
            )
            for c in df.columns
        ],
        axis=1,
    ).set_axis(df.columns, axis=1).set_axis(df.index, axis=0).dropna(how="all")
# 86.3 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: It is not clear what are actually the variables in the code. A minimal reproducible example would help a lot. For example, what is the *exact* dtype and shape of `idx` and `data`, and are `h1` and `h2` scalar (and if so are they integers or floats)?

Comment: Btw, be aware that the Numba compilation time can be quite slow so the function needs to run long enough so the overhead is small (or be executed many many times otherwise for the same reason). Currently, we have no information about actual timings although this is a performance related question...

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have added an example with timing, and I have clarified the arguments types.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Interestingly, it is twice faster on my machine, not twice slower (30 ms vs 16-17.5 ms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Numba code is rather **memory-bound**. In fact, worst : it is even **page-fault bound**. This is certainly why it is faster on my machine and slower on your machine (my machine has been design to achieve a high throughput) : it is more efficient if the RAM throughput is high enough. RAM throughput is very precious these days because of the **memory-wall** (and this is not gonna be better any time soon -- actually, it should be quite the opposite).

Consequently, the key here is to **reduce the memory pressure**. `np.full_like(data, np.nan)` can be replaced by `np.empty_like(data)` so to avoid filling the RAM for no reason since the contant of `out` is overwritten in the loop just after. This makes the Numba function `pct_change_h1_h2_njit` 22% faster on my machine.

The column-based version si slower than the row-based one here because the Pandas dataframe is **initialized with a row-major Numpy arrays**. In practice though, Pandas dataframe generally contains a set of multiple Numpy arrays for each column, so they are more column-major. This means **this benchmark is certainly not representative of the actual timings you will get**.

Besides, in Numba, loops are generally better since they **avoid creating temporary arrays** which are expensive (not much here since they can be stored in the CPU L1 cache). More specifically, `v / denominator[i]` can be replaced by a loop. This is slightly faster on my machine.

Note that `pct_change_h1_h2_njit` takes only 60% of the whole computation. The `dropna` part is also a bit slow.

Ideally, the code should be *parallelized*, but this is not easy for this function. This would reduce the overhead of *page-faults* on most systems.

Alternatively, you can **recycle the output array** by pre-allocating it, passing it in parameter and writing it in the function. This is the key optimization. It makes the function 2.4 times faster on my machine compared to the previous version and nearly **3 times faster** than the initial version. Here is the code:

```py
@numba.njit(error_model="numpy")  # expected to be multiples faster
def pct_change_h1_h2_njit(idx, data, h1, h2, out):
    zeroes = np.full_like(out[0], 0)
    denominator = out[0]

    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        if idx[i] == h1:
            denominator = v
            out[i].fill(np.nan)
        elif idx[i] == h2:
            if np.isnan(denominator).all():
                out[i].fill(0)
            else:
                for j in range(out[i].shape[0]):
                    out[i,j] = v[j] / denominator[j] - 1
        else:
            out[i].fill(np.nan)

    return out # Not really needed
```

I know that creating new arrays is more convenient, but this is a bad practice performance-wise (despite this is the standard way to program with Numpy and Pandas). At this point, `dropna` tends to takes a big portion of the running time but there is not much to do to reduce its execution appart not using Pandas to do that... The `pct_change_h1_h2_njit` function succeed to reach the memory throughput of 28 GiB/s. This is very good for a sequential code on my machine and I do not think it can be made significantly faster without using more cores. I think the **`dropna` function is also memory-bound**. Thus, merging the two functions in one bigger function (if possible) should result in a nearly twice faster implementation!

Note that there is a **bug** in the second column-based function: `np.nan == np.nan` is always `False` by definition, so `np.nan in exceptions` will never be `True` even if `np.Nan` is in `exceptions`. **You must use `np.isnan`**.

Comment: Great explanation of the shortcomings for someone not used to numba and the finer subtleties of memory management, like I am. This is truly very helpful, thank you very much. So I believe in the above code, I should replace np.full_like by np.empty_like? Also, the dropna is, as you can see, done only because I'm keeping only one row per day but I could certainly manually create such an index outside of numba, then I would only need to generate a shorter list. Ideally extending (would make it easier) otherwise I can count how many rows it should have. What do you suggest is the best way?

Comment: When I call the new function (removing the `zeroes` line, as not needed anymore), and passing as `out` argument `df[df.columns[0]].values`, I get an error `TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'fill' of type float64`

Comment: nevermind: When I call the new function passing `df.copy().values` as out, it works well but gives a timing similar to the asfreq method. Memory limitation of my rig I suppose.

Comment: *"I should replace np.full_like by np.empty_like?"* As stated in the answer, yes. But if you pre-allocate the output and reuse it many times, it does not matter much. I did not understand the second question.

Comment: For the error, it seems `out` is a 1D array so `out[i]` is a float64 value, hence the error. Note that `out` is supposed to be a pre-allocated Numpy array. Operating on dataframe content can certainly work but data may be copied by Pandas resulting in an inefficient code. Copying the whole dataframe takes about half the time of the whole optimized implementation so this is clearly something to avoid. I guess this answer your last comment.

Comment: By the way, note that you can use simple-precision if you do not care about having more than ~6 digits precision (which is actually quite a lot assuming the algorithms are precise).